# Core Image: Photo effect react/change slowly in real iPhone when changing intensity from a Slider

Tags: performance, swiftui, core-image

The below code apply an image Picker and showing filtered image in contentView, in this case I used SepiaTone effect. When I do the movements in slider, to change the filter intensity. The photo react delay and the sliding is not fluent.

But when using some apps from App Store like "Afterlight", with their photo filter, the changing to photo effect is smoothly when a user moves a slider.

So what is the different, is those apps use other framework? How could we improve the performance on continuously changing filter intensity if we still use Core Image?

### ImagePicker

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            }

            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }
}
```

### ContentView

```
import CoreImage
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var filterIntensity = 0.5

    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?

    @State private var currentFilter = CIFilter.sepiaTone()
    let context = CIContext()

    var body: some View {
        let intensity = Binding<Double>(
            get: {
                self.filterIntensity
        },
            set: {
                self.filterIntensity = $0
                self.applyProcessing()
        })

        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary)

                    if image != nil {
                        image?
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    } else {
                        Text("Tap to select a picture")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showingImagePicker = true
                }

                HStack {
                    Text("Intensity")
                    Slider(value: intensity)
                }
                .padding(.vertical)

                HStack {
                    Button("Change Filter") {
                        // change filter
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    Button("Save") {
                        // save the picture
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
            .navigationBarTitle("Instafilter")
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage)
            }
        }
    }

    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }

        let beginImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
        currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        applyProcessing()
    }

    func applyProcessing() {
        currentFilter.intensity = Float(filterIntensity)
        guard let outputImage = currentFilter.outputImage else { return }

        if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to perform the image filter in a background thread to not block the main queue with the image processing. Also, it would make sense to not react to every single change but to debounce changes: wait for a short amount like 50ms of no change before the actual computation is done - this prevents a large number of image computations to happen if the filter params change often in a short time (like when the user drags the slider around). Both can be achieved using the Combine framework, here is an example based on your code. The effect is separated in a separate class `ImageEffect` that uses Combine to perform the image processing in the background whenever inputImage/filterIntensity changes, optimized using the [debounce operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher/3204205-debounce):

```swift
import CoreImage
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ImageEffect: ObservableObject {

    @Published var filterIntensity = 0.5
    @Published var inputImage: UIImage?
    @Published var outputImage: UIImage?

    @Published var currentFilter = CIFilter.sepiaTone()
    let context = CIContext()
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Image processing")

    init() {
        self.$inputImage
            .map { inputImage -> CIImage? in
                guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return nil }
                return CIImage(image: inputImage)
            }
            .combineLatest(self.$filterIntensity)
            .debounce(for: .milliseconds(50), scheduler: queue)
            .map { inputImage, filterIntensity -> UIImage? in
                guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return nil }

                self.currentFilter.inputImage = inputImage
                self.currentFilter.intensity = Float(filterIntensity)

                guard let outputImage = self.currentFilter.outputImage else { return nil }

                guard let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) else { return nil }

                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

            }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { image in
                self.outputImage = image
            }
            .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
    }

}

struct ImageEffectView: View {

    @ObservedObject var imageEffect = ImageEffect()
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary)

                    if imageEffect.outputImage != nil {
                        Image(uiImage: imageEffect.outputImage!)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    } else {
                        Text("Tap to select a picture")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showingImagePicker = true
                }

                HStack {
                    Text("Intensity")
                    Slider(value: $imageEffect.filterIntensity)
                }
                .padding(.vertical)

                HStack {
                    Button("Change Filter") {
                        // change filter
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    Button("Save") {
                        // save the picture
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
            .navigationBarTitle("Instafilter")
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker) {
                ImagePickerView(image: self.$imageEffect.inputImage)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it and get back to you soon!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have applied your code, now the slider movement is more smoothly than before, no laggy any more. Good to know you are using Combine here, I used to used Combine to handle some JSON API request. I could see that ```inputImage``` in ```ImageEffect``` is connected/binding with ```image``` of ```ImagePicker```, so they will change together. And ```debounce``` will delay 50ms of image processing, then the slider moves, the change effect of filter intensity will not take effect immediately. Thanks for it, I learn a new thing here.

Comment: For better user experience, I want the intensity change take effect immediately. But if I remove the ```debounce``` of delaying, then the slider movement is back to laggy state as before. Instead I could see apps like "AfterLight" could handle slider changing fast, e.g. even I slide to left then right rapidly again & again. The filter intensity effect was reflect on the showed image immediately, very good performance & user experience, I'm wondering what technique/framework they are using?

Comment: 50ms is almost not noticeable, the interval could be even shorter. you could also get it faster by downsizing the image to screen size just once to a smaller size (using a map operation on the image) and then applying the image effect to that image.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I could let slider to send the changes continuously, I found that the image filter effect is applied when the slider moving is done. So maybe it is doing it only when a user's movement is finished. Not sure how slider will send out the value changes by default, but I will look into it too.

Comment: Ah, I found an interesting thing, if I remove ```debounce``` then slider changes will not update continuously. However if I keep it then continuous updates from slider.